# Exception: SDL2: Unable to load image - When running kivy apk on android

Tags: python, android, kivy, apk, kivymd

I created this very simple app, just as a demo. Then to run it on android, I converted it into an APK with buildozer. The conversion was successful, but when I tried running my app, it crashed. I tried to debug it with adb logcat and got this error-

```
12-23 10:15:00.913 22282 22454 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
12-23 10:15:00.913 22282 22454 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 82, in <module>
12-23 10:15:00.913 22282 22454 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/popcat/kivy/app.py", line 950, in run
12-23 10:15:00.914 22282 22454 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/popcat/kivy/base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
12-23 10:15:00.914 22282 22454 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/popcat/kivy/base.py", line 347, in mainloop
12-23 10:15:00.914 22282 22454 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/popcat/kivy/base.py", line 395, in idle
12-23 10:15:00.914 22282 22454 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/popcat/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 793, in sync
12-23 10:15:00.915 22282 22454 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/popcat/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 69, in call_fn
12-23 10:15:00.915 22282 22454 I python  :    File "kivy/graphics/instructions.pyx", line 366, in kivy.graphics.instructions.VertexInstruction.source.__set__
12-23 10:15:00.915 22282 22454 I python  :    File "kivy/graphics/context_instructions.pyx", line 430, in kivy.graphics.context_instructions.BindTexture.source.__set__
12-23 10:15:00.915 22282 22454 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/popcat/kivy/core/image/__init__.py", line 561, in __init__
12-23 10:15:00.916 22282 22454 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/popcat/kivy/core/image/__init__.py", line 754, in _set_filename
12-23 10:15:00.916 22282 22454 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/popcat/kivy/core/image/__init__.py", line 460, in load
12-23 10:15:00.916 22282 22454 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/popcat/kivy/core/image/__init__.py", line 223, in __init__
12-23 10:15:00.917 22282 22454 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/popcat/kivy/core/image/img_sdl2.py", line 47, in load
12-23 10:15:00.917 22282 22454 I python  :  Exception: SDL2: Unable to load image
12-23 10:15:00.917 22282 22454 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

I have no clue why this is happening. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please, add the  minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in the code seems to work-

```
import os
os.environ['KIVY_IMAGE'] = 'pil,sdl2'
```